# catalogsearch url being spammed by chinese bots

Tags: search, catalogsearch

Constantly getting hits on our site search **catalogsearch** url by what appear to be **Chinese bots** from mainly China, e.g.

```
/catalogsearch/result/?q=大奖娱乐88tb88手机版+Q82019309.com.com
```

I have blocked a lot of IP ranges for **China**, **Russia** and **Ukraine**. Some **individual IP addresses are also blocked ** from other countries like **Germany**.

The only one that seems to be active now is one that is supposed to be a **GoogleBot**, several in the `66.249.76.114` range.

Other than IP blocking, all I could think of was copying  `Data.php` to

```
/app/code/local/ from /app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Helper/
```

and changing the public function `getQueryText()` to catch searches that had `.com` in the string.

I changed the string randomly to something more befitting what the store sells using a small array of products. Only tested so far, see below!

```
if ($this->_queryText === null) {
   $this->_queryText = '';
} elseif (strtolower(strpos($this->_queryText, '.com')) !== false) {
   $botitems = Array("* product 1","* product 2","* product 3","* product 4","* product 5","* product 6","* product 7","* product 8","* product 9");
   $this->_queryText = $botitems[rand(0, count($botitems) - 1)];
} else {
   /* @var $stringHelper Mage_Core_Helper_String */
   $stringHelper = Mage::helper('core/string');
```

**Questions are:**

1. Is there any other way to stop bots using the search string?
2. Will these hits cause any problems with site ranking?
3. other than i.p. blocking is changing the search query when they hit a good or bad idea?
4. Is the bot that looks like a Googlebot legit?
5. What are they up to?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Some context: 
We were having the same issue since 2 weeks with the same URL (Q82019309.com) with variation. We started by blocking all IP range from China + Russia like you did and also added [this bot list](https://github.com/bluedragonz/bad-bot-blocker/blob/master/.htaccess) with no success.

To answer your questions: 
1) We extended getQueryText like you suggested and kill the search if the parameter contains ".com" .

Here is the code we used:

```
elseif (strpos(strtolower($this->_queryText, '.com')) !== false) {
    die();
} else {
```

Your code will always return true if you don't switch strpos & strtolower. (It did on my end).

2) It might on the long run. If your magento website ends up with thousand of spammy results webpage. Once you extanded your search function, don't forget to delete the result page in Magento.

3) As stated earlier, IP blocking has been an unsuccessful cat of mouse game and we ended the same way you did.

4) This bot is not legit. The only reason we found for this behaviour was some lame black hat SEO to optimize the URL ( magento create a page for the search term that is indexed by google and then rank up the site).

To be totally fair i wont promise that's the best solution but it worked for no downside in our case.

Let me know if you found another solution.

Comment: Thanks Maz for the help
Late night inclusion of strtolower() and didn't test, doh! Also see I had bracket in wrong place - 
elseif (strpos(strtolower($this->_queryText), '.com') !== false) {. I did try die(); and on reflection looks the best option as it looks like it has no Google impact, I think?!

Answer (score 0):

One solutions is to simply Disalow search results page from robots.txt file. Google will not index all search results. Then simply delete all spammy search results in Magento every fews or so.

This spam affects sites that do not Disalow /catalogsearch/ from robots.txt.

Comment: Thanks for the help Icon. robots.txt already has Disalow /catalogsearch/ but Google still tracks it in Analytics!?

Comment: Simply ignore, MILLIONS of sites being affected by this spam issue.... one thingI can reccommend is to limit the number string length of search query.. go to System- configuration- catalog-catalog . Look for search setting tab, once you find it change the Max lengh from 126 letters to 15 or 20. Basically the spam links will be cut short and Non executable even if they show up in google

Comment: This is just another bad seo tactic, I would  NOT worry much about it.